# NSTableView row - changing colors when highlighting

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I've got a view-based NSTableView that I set a custom highlight color for by overriding `drawSelectionInRect` in the NSTableRowView subclass.

Initially, I noticed that the text automatically changed from a dark color to a light color when I clicked it (though lately it only does this intermittently). I also have graphics in this table row view which have poor contrast when the row is highlighted, so I implemented `tableViewSelectionDidChange` in my table view's delegate.

It worked great and everything, except that `tableViewSelectionDidChange` doesn't get called until *after* I release the mouse button. When I use the keyboard to change selection `tableViewSelectionDidChange` fires immediately.

My two major questions here:

- Can I make `tableViewSelectionDidChange` fire immediately instead of on mouseUp?
- Is there something I can do to ensure that the text in my row view reliably changes to white when the row's selected?

I checked to see how Apple apps handle this. I looked at Mail.app and clicked a row in the messages list (it contains the attachment paper clip icon). Mail handles it by not changing the row color until mouse up. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: There is a `tableViewSelectionIsChanging:` delegate method that appears to be perfectly suited to your purposes, no?  If not, why not?

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for; I can't believe I didn't notice it in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I put it as the answer, then, to get the credit for it.  :->  I wasn't expecting this to be so easy!  :->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `tableViewSelectionIsChanging:` delegate method that appears to be perfectly suited to your purposes, no?